# How can I convert lat-long to county?

Tags: r

As a part of a longer code, I have this line to convert from lat-long to county.

```
county<-latlong2county(latlon)
```

where

```
dput(droplevels(head(latlon, 4)))
```

is

```
structure(list(alldata.lon = c(-71.566389, -71.566389, -71.566389, 
-71.566389), alldata.lat = c(41.69, 41.69, 41.69, 41.69)), .Names = c("alldata.lon", 
"alldata.lat"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

It was working fine till a month back. But now I am getting an error at this point:

```
Error in CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=wgs84") : 
  unknown elliptical parameter name
```

Not sure what changed. Maybe something in the original maps package. Can you help?

**FUNCTION**

```
latlong2county <- function(pointsDF) {
  # Prepare SpatialPolygons object with one SpatialPolygon
  # per state (plus DC, minus HI & AK)
  states <- map('county', fill=TRUE, col="transparent", plot=FALSE)
  IDs <- sapply(strsplit(states$names, ":"), function(x) x[1])
  states_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(states, IDs=IDs,
                                   proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=wgs84"))

  # Convert pointsDF to a SpatialPoints object 
  pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(pointsDF, 
                            proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=wgs84"))

  # Use 'over' to get _indices_ of the Polygons object containing each point 
  indices <- over(pointsSP, states_sp)

  # Return the state names of the Polygons object containing each point
  stateNames <- sapply(states_sp@polygons, function(x) x@ID)
  stateNames[indices]
}
```

Comment: Doesn't like lowercase `"wgs84"`. Use `CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")`.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a recent change? I ran it for more than a year without troubles.